# Is this possible to have a live update into a 2nd workbook referencing cell values from the first in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document that is used by everyone in the office.  When someone is in it the rest use a read only or have to wait to update.  I have created a new workbook that references the working copy. Eg cell contents are =path[document]Sheet!cell is there a way to automatically view changes as they are input on the working copy.  This would be a read only solution but ideally a right up to date copy of the working workbook. A solution through excel or VBA button click would be ideal. Can you help. I have tried connections but it crashes and only updates on a close and save from another user.  When I have both docs open on my computer updates are instant.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not [sharing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534) or [co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104) the workbook?

Comment: Have you considered using google docs? This way multiple users can update at once and if needed you can pull this back into your excel doc

Comment: It is in an office environment we have what we have and can't add new software. I have tested shared docs however the workbook is updated constantly and there would be too many conflicts.  Ideally a web based database with a backend server would be the best solution but I'm trying to make the best of what is available